# Populate app with buttons on Ruby Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'd like to know how to populate an application interface with many buttons. For example, I'd like to make 100 buttons. I saw an example with simple-calc.rb, but there would be a way of doing this without typing a list of 100 numbers.
Here is the code:

```
# Simple buttons
Shoes.app(title: "Alabord 0.0", width:560, height: 300, resizable: false) do

    flow :width => 600, :margin => 4 do
      %w(1 2 3 4 100).each do |btn|
      button btn
     end
    end
    stack :margin => 4 do
        button "Quit" do
            exit()
        end
    end
end
```

[App window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnCOl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Shoes.app(title: "Alabord 0.0", width:560, height: 300, resizable: false) do

flow :width => 600, :margin => 4 do
  (1..100).each do |btn|
    button btn
  end
end

stack :margin => 4 do
  button "Quit" do
    exit
  end
end
```

Comment: Didn't work. The buttons don't show up with this modification.

Comment: It was missing a name for the buttons. It worked as soon as changed: button "P_"+btn.to_s